# Error in "ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView", list_layout.xml

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, sqlite

I have this error, after reading several other questions on here regarding the same thing I haven't yet found an answer. The ArrayAdapter is asking for a resource ID for the TextView. I have set this but it doesnt work for some reason. Any help would be great thanks.

`ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView`

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtReceiptID"
    android:text="@string/receipt_id"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtReceiptURI"
    android:text="@string/receipt_picture"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

This is my activity

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ReceiptsListView);
    receiptDataAdapter = new ReceiptDataAdapter(getApplication(),R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(receiptDataAdapter);
    receiptsoperations = new ReceiptsOperations(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = receiptsoperations.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = receiptsoperations.getReceiptsURI(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

            String receiptID,receiptURI;
            receiptID = cursor.getString(0);
            receiptURI = cursor.getString(1);
            ReceiptProvider receiptprovider = new ReceiptProvider(receiptID, receiptURI);
            receiptDataAdapter.add(receiptprovider);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Or maybe it is in the DataAdapter where it is wrong?

```
public class ReceiptDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter   {
List list = new ArrayList();
public ReceiptDataAdapter(Context context, int resource)
{
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler
{
    TextView RECEIPTID, RECEIPTURI;
}

@Override
public void add(Object object)
{
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);

}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){

    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.RECEIPTID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiptID);
        //change this for picture rather than text
        layoutHandler.RECEIPTURI = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiptURI);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    }
    else
    {

        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

    }
    ReceiptProvider receiptProvider = (ReceiptProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.RECEIPTID.setText(receiptProvider.getReceiptID());
    layoutHandler.RECEIPTURI.setText(receiptProvider.getReceiptURI());


    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

Full LogCat error

```
You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-21 12:17:12.532 17135-17135/com.example.section32point5.digiceit       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.section32point5.digiceit, PID: 17135
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                                                      at com.example.section32point5.digiceit.ReceiptDataAdapter.getView(ReceiptDataAdapter.java:74)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2421)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893)
                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2693)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2204)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1283)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1174)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6241)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:676)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369) 
                                                                                      at com.example.section32point5.digiceit.ReceiptDataAdapter.getView(ReceiptDataAdapter.java:74) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2421) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5966) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2693) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18893) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2204) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1283) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1522) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1174) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6241) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:676) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Show your `ReceiptDataAdapter`.

Comment: Show your logcat error

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have added the LogCat error and the ReceiptDataAdapter.

Comment: where is the code of ReceiptDataAdapter.? if the provided one is the code, then where you are passing list  to display? and where you are using list present inside.? 1st refer some sites for basic use of array adapter.

Comment: see my edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767924/error-in-arrayadapter-you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview-list-layo/36769051#36769051

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because you are not provided any resource id to display item. call super class constructor of `ReceiptDataAdapter`. like

```
public class ReceiptDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter   {
  List list = new ArrayList();
  public ReceiptDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource, R.id.txtReceiptID/*resourceId in adapter item layout*/ );
  }
//your code if any present
}
```

I think you should 1st refer how to use array adapter [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

**EDIT :**

oh man. there is no need of calling `getView` of super class again. simply return `row` view .

Comment: It has gotten rid of the first error. Unfortunately it is now saying that the RECEIPTID is Null.

Comment: as per your code it should not come . once update your code.

Comment: I have read the document unfortunately I am still struggling with this. Could you please advise where I am going wrong, rather than telling me I am going wrong.